# Insert rows with a custom cell into table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In my `tableView` there is five rows that always exist in the table ,,, when I tap on one of them new three rows will appear under the tapped one.

If the first five rows is a default `UITableViewCell` ,,, I want the three cells also to be from another custom cell; so the main five cells will be different from the the secondary rows (three under the main cell).

Here is how I add the secondary rows :

In `tableView` delegate `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` :

```
NSInteger count = indexPath.row + 1;
NSMutableArray *newRows = [NSMutableArray array];//

   self.expandedIndex = indexPath.row + 1;
   self.tableExpanded = YES;

   for(int i = 0; i < [self.numbers count]; i++)
   {
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0];
        [newRows addObject:path];
        [self.myArray insertObject:[self.numbers objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:count];
        count++;
   }

     [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

The rows added but I want them to be from the custom cell that I want to create ,,, any ideas

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. I would make `newRows` a property and then at the end of `didSelectRowAt...` I would call table refresh. Then in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check to see if the specific indexPath is in `newRows`, if it is use a different cell style:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if ([self.newRows contains:indexPath]) {
        // create custom cell
    } else {
        // create normal cell
    }

    return cell;
}
```

If this does not make sense let me know and I can elaborate.

Also note, you will have some interesting edge cases to handle. For example, if the user clicks on the 3rd cell and new cells are inserted into rows 4-6, and they later click on cell 2, adding new cells in rows 3-5, then the previous 4-6 cells will now be at rows 7-9. I am not sure how you are you are structuring your app so this may not be an issue (like maybe on one of the five cells can have subcells added at a time) but just realize that this is a possibility.